# $f(x)=x(x-2)(x-6),\;\int_0^2f(x)dx-\int_2^6f(x)dx=\frac{148}{3}$. $g(x)=f(ax+b)$. Find $a$ and $b$ if $\int_4^0g(x)dx+\int_4^6g(x)dx=\frac{148}{3}$

Tags: integration

This is a problem from a high school test (the test is over and the answers are available).

> The function $f(x)=x(x-2)(x-6)$ is given.
>
> The diagram shows the area bounded by $y=f(x)$ and the $x$-axis.[image: Graph of shaded area]
>
> (a) Find the exact shaded area.
>
> (b) Let $g(x)=f(ax+b)$. Find $a$ and $b$ if $\int_4^0g(x)dx+\int_4^6g(x)dx$ has the same area calculated in part (a).

I did part (a); the working is below:

$f(x)=x^3-8x^2+12x$.

The area is

$
\begin{align*}
&\int_0^2(x^3-8x^2+12x)dx-\int_2^6(x^3-8x^2+12x)dx\\
&=\left[\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac83x^3+6x^2\right]_0^2-\left[\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac83x^3+6x^2\right]_2^6\\
&=\frac{20}{3}-\left(-36-\frac{20}{3}\right)\\
&=\frac{148}{3}
\end{align*}
$

However, I cannot figure out part (b). The answer given says:

> [image: Answer graphs]$\int_4^0g(x)dx+\int_4^6g(x)dx=-\int_0^4g(x)dx+\int_4^6g(x)dx$
>
> $g(x)$ is obtained by reflecting $f(x)$ horizontally and then shifting it $6$ units to the right.
>
> $\therefore g(x)=f(-x+6)\implies a=-1,\;b=6$

I do not understand how they conclude that "$g(x)$ is obtained by reflecting $f(x)$ horizontally and then shifting it $6$ units to the right." I know that "$\int_4^0g(x)dx+\int_4^6g(x)dx=-\int_0^4g(x)dx+\int_4^6g(x)dx$", they just flipped the limits of integration and added a negative sign.

The graph of $g(x)$ in the image (I assume it is the dotted line) crosses a zero in the interval in the integral (from $0$ to $4$), and, to my knowledge, when calculating area, we always avoid integrating across zeroes and split up the integral into the area above and the area below the $x$-axis. So I do not understand how this area is calculated.

I would appreciate a brief explanation of the solution given for part (b), or an alternative simpler method (using high school methods only).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)$ is a real-valued continuous function on $[a,b]$ and $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$ in $[a.b]$ then  $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$$

See the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus). Thus we have
$$\int_{0}^{2}f(x)dx-\int_{2}^{6}f(x)dx=F(2)-F(0)-(F(6)-F(2))=2F(2)-F(0)-F(6).$$
On the other hand $$\int_{4}^{0}g(x)dx+\int_{4}^{6}g(x)=dx\int_{4}^{0}f(ax+b)dx+\int_{4}^{6}f(ax+b)dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{a}\int_{4a+b}^{b}f(u)du+\frac{1}{a}\int_{4a+b}^{6a+b}f(u)du$$
$$=\frac{1}{a}\big[F(b)-F(4a+b)+F(6a+b)-F(4a+b)\big]$$
$$=\frac{1}{a}\big[F(b)+F(6a+b)-2F(4a+b)\big]$$

where we have used the substitution $u=ax+b.$ Now comparing terms above it is easy to see that $a=-1$ and $b=6.$

Geometrically you can see that the two areas are the same from the sketch above. Alternatively since you know $f(x)=x^3-8x^2+12x,$ then $$g(x)=f(ax+b)=(ax+b)^{3}-8(ax+b)^{2}+12(ax+b)$$
$$=a^3x^3+3a^2bx^2-8a^2x^2+3ab^2x-16abx+12ax+b^3-8b^2+12b.$$

So you can compute the integrals directly and determine which $a$ and $b$ to choose, but that's not going to take $10$ minutes...

Comment: Is there meant to be a $\frac1a$ in front of those integrals?

Comment: Yeah since $u=ax+b$ so $du=adx$ and $dx=\frac{du}{a}.$ Comparing $2F(2)$ and $-\frac{1}{a}2F(4a+b)$, you see that $a=-1$ and $b=6$ for example.

Comment: If I compare the terms and find $a$ and $b$ that way, aren't I assuming that the $F(x)$ is the same as $F(u)$ (the antiderivative of $f$ is the same as the antiderivative of $g$)? They are different functions, so how can this be the case?

Comment: No since we used that $g(x)=f(ax+b)$ and made the change of variable, so we are integrating $f$ in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Because the graph is shifted by $6$ and only reflected on the $y$-axis ($x\rightarrow -x$ so that the graph is not stretched) you can see that the area of the original curve $f(x)$ from 2 to 6 (blue curve) is the same as the area between 0 and 4 of $f(-x+6)$ (red curve). Likewise the area between 4 and 6 of $f(-x+6)$ is the same as the area between 0 and 2 of $f(x)$.

Note the substitution $$\int_4^6 f(6-x) \, {\rm d}x \stackrel{t=6-x}{=}\int_0^2 f(t) \, {\rm d}t \\ \int_0^4 f(6-x) \, {\rm d}x \stackrel{t=6-x}{=}\int_2^6 f(t) \, {\rm d}t \, .$$

One way of seeing this would be to realize that the first integral in $$-\int_0^4f(ax+b)\, {\rm d}x+\int_4^6f(ax+b) \, {\rm d}x$$
is over an interval of length 4, while the second is over an interval of length 2 and so are the intervals of your original integral. Thus you could have tried $$-\int_0^4 f(ax+b) \, {\rm d}x \stackrel{t=ax+b}{=} a^{-1} \int_{4a+b}^b f(t) \, {\rm d}t$$
and notice that this integral becomes $-\int_2^6 f(x) \, {\rm d}x$ in the case $a=-1$ and $b=6$.

Comment: But how can I figure out that the graph is shifted by 6 and reflected on the y-axis?

Comment: You mean how would you have come to the conclusion in an exam situation?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Getting the answer from the beginning.